# Flutter riverpod provider not updating state in UI

Tags: android, flutter, api, riverpod

I'm right now connecting my flutter mobile app to the backend API, and i am using providers from Riverpod packagee, as a way to reload the widget when there is data changes.

The provider that i am using is ChangeNotifierProvider.
And i notice one thing, i am creating now the user account, where they can view their profile and edit it. While calling the api the values will be null, but when the provider gets the data shoudl reload the widget and show the data in the form fields with the data that came from the backend.

This is how my provider is working, it gets a parameter of type String, that will be the user id
and then it will call the backend to fetch the data from that user.

[image]

After that i have the class UserProxy, that will do the backend call, and on the user screen i have a listener, like this
[image]

After that in the form initial data i have called the user data that comes from the backend to show as initial data
[image]

But the problem here is the thing, as you can see in the console i have a print, where i print the username to check if any data passes, and it does, but the UI doesnt update as you can see
[image]

if you see it comes first null, obviously, sisnce the backend is still beeing called but then it gets the username, but the UI doesnt update...

Any help will be amazing, thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Well i figure it out, the problem was that i was using a initial value in the TextFormFiled, instead of using the controller, because that is the one who checks for changes, here is how my code works now, just needed to change the form field:
[image]